# Is there any other better method for Overriding Model Serializer Update Method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am created a model Serializer and overriding the methods .But in this case I need to save each serializer object one by one ....

I am checking is there any other methods

```
class PetSerializer(ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        exclude = ['name', 'categoty','color','food']

     def update(self, instance, validated_data):
          instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
          instance.categoty = validated_data.get('categoty', instance.categoty)
          instance.color = validated_data.get('color', instance.color)
          instance.food = validated_data.get('food', instance.food)
          instance.save()
```

In this case If I am having 10 fields I need to save one by one right ?

Is there any other better way to handle this ?

Answer (score 3):

this is more of a Python question ;)

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for field_name in ('name', 'category', 'colour', 'food'):
        setattr(instance, field_name, validated_data.get(field_name, getattr(instance, field_name))
    instance.save()
```

Python allows object attribute manipulation with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

PS: please note that relational data may require a different handling as it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Is there any other method to get  the field names??? Here we are passing as a string right ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: for field_name in ('name', 'category', 'colour', 'food'):

In this I am specifying my entire field names and loop through it right ?

Comment: Instead of that I found that solution